# Replacing all images in a CSS file with base64 encoded strings from the command line

Tags: css, command-line, sed, base64

Basically I'm trying to write a clever single line of commands that outputs base64 encoded strings in place of where there used to be a path to an image. So:

```
background-image: url(path/to/my/image.png);
```

…would turn into:

```
background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,ABvR0…+tC==);
```

I normally turn an image into its base64 encoded string via:

```
openssl enc -base64 -in path/to/my/image.png
```

Which outputs the base64… but with newlines in it. This is fixed by piping it through `tr` like:

```
openssl enc -base64 -in path/to/my/image.png | tr -d '\n'
```

which just outputs a long base64 encoded string. By using pbcopy (on Mac OS) that gets sent to the clipboard, like so:

```
openssl enc -base64 -in path/to/my/image.png | tr -d '\n' | pbcopy
```

Very nice for ad hoc replacing an occasional image with its base64 representation but what I'd like to do is have this automated for replacing all occurrences of `url(path/to/whatever.ext)` in a file by their respective base64 strings. Making sure there are only actual paths and no data-uris in there is out of scope here :)

I have been trying to replace stuff with `sed` but I got stuck in its horrible documentation. It's not too difficult to find the occurences of the `url(…)` pattern in a css file, but the bit between parenthesis needs to be replaced by the output of the above command and I am clueless if this is at all possible. So, there it is, help or some pointers (do I need to look into awk as well?) would be much appreciated! A 'you cannot do this without a proper script' would also do of course :)

Comment: Don't do that unless you want your images not to work in 50% of user's browsers (IE 6, 7, 8). Try again in a couple of years.

Comment: Typically this is done when developing for (some) mobile browsers to reduce HTTP overhead, so IE 6 is not an issue.

Comment: @Ben Noted. However, I have the luxury of not having to care about IE6. There is an mhtml solution for IE7 and it works perfectly in IE8.

Comment: Check out [Juicer](https://github.com/cjohansen/juicer).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### With `openssl` tool

```
#!/bin/bash

awk -F'[()]' -v q="'" '

/background-image: url(.*)/ {
  cmd=sprintf("openssl enc -base64 -in %s | tr -d %c\\n%c",$2,q,q)
  cmd | getline b64
  close(cmd)
  $0=$1 "(data:image/png;base64," b64 ");"
}1' /path/to/css/file
```

#### Proof of Concept

See [**HERE**](http://www.ideone.com/Ma92I) for a working example

---

#### With `base64` tool

```
#!/bin/bash

awk -F'[()]' '

/background-image: url(.*)/ {
  cmd=sprintf("base64 -w0 %s",$2)
  cmd | getline b64
  close(cmd)
  $0=$1 "(data:image/png;base64," b64 ");"
}1' /path/to/css/file
```

#### Proof of Concept

See [**HERE**](http://www.ideone.com/vwmhu) for a working example

Comment: This looks kind of promising but I don't have the `base64` tool (but I suppose I could easily write a script that uses `openssl` and `tr`). However, I can't get it to work. I'm not 100% but from experience I know that not all Mac OS X unix commands are exactly the same as their Linux counterparts.

Comment: @Matijs see my updated answer. The reason you didn't get it to work is most likely due to the fact that you have to use a variable for the single quotes around `tr '\n'`.  If you tried to use a literal single quote, it will interfere with the single quotes surrounding the entire awk script which are there to prevent the shell from interpreting any of the awk characters.

Comment: @SiegeX you sir, are a command line hero! This seems to almost do what I was looking for, however it opens too many files. Right now there are about 120 background images in the .css file already. Any tips on awk not opening this many files?

Comment: @Matijs when you say "opens too many files", are you getting an error that is stating as such?

Comment: @Matijs: I've updated the answer to include `close()` which should eliminate your errors

Comment: @SiegeX that was indeed the error, and `close()` did solve it! Fantastic! Thanks a lot, where's +2 when you need it?

Comment: @Matijs: glad to help. You can +1 my other answers for your questions on awk, sed, bash or command-line =).

Comment: @Matijs I just took care of the extra +1 for @SiegeX :) Great answer.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using Perl rather than sed. Skip awk altogether, its awkward :-). (Actually it was one of the first programming languages I learned, but Perl is much better).

Better still, don't do that at all as it won't work in 50% of users' browsers. At any rate, be very, very sure you don't care about those users, before you *tell them so* in this way.

Comment: From the example by @SiegeX, yes, awk is awkward :) however, I was hoping for a command line solution that fitted on a single line. I'm not so sure that's possible on a Mac anymore. Thanks for your suggestion though.

Comment: @Matijs its `awk`ward because if you know what you're doing, you can make awk code quite terse by using shortcuts. I used a number of said shortcuts in my code.  If I did everything the long way it's actually quite readable; it looks a lot like C-code; but it will be 2x as long.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a lot of experience with ccs and png files, but given your **very helpful** *I have this string, I want that string* descriptions, Here's a first draft

```
#! /bin/ksh # -vx  (bash should work too)

usageMsg="pngReplacer pngFile ccsFile"
case $# in
  [!2] ) print "usage: ${usageMsg}"  ; exit 1
esac
set -- ${@}  # I'm surprised that we need this line
base64Str=$(openssl enc -base64 -in "$1" 2>/dev/null | tr -d '\n')

{
   if ${testMode:-false} ; then
        print -- " background-image: url(path/to/my/image.png);"
   else 
        cat "$2"
   fi
} | sed 's@url(.*)@url(data:image/png;base64,'"$base64Str"')@g'
```

Lots of fragility here

- do I have this right, png file and css file, right?
- you know about ksh/bash $1 $2 etc arguments, right?
- the test for argument count is ok, but
- you'd probably really want to confirm that $1 and $2 really exist
- no opportunity to specify an outputFile, run it as

pngReplacer pngFile ccsFile > newCcsFile

- if the stuff in { } gives you the heebie-geebies, you could cut it all out, right to the '|' char just before the sed, and put the $2 at the end of the sed command.
- I would be surprised if AIX sed could handle a 280 char replacement expression, but I don't have it handy to test with anymore. In general, seds are fragile about things like that.
- biggest fragility of all, the @reg-exp@replace-exp@ delimiter (@). If you wind up with an @ sign in the base64Str, then you'll have to find a char to use that is not in the new base64Str.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This command line I wrote encodes all images contained into an HTML file instead.

It can easily be adapted to encode all images in a CSS file (by editing the *base64images* function).

It just requires the PHP command line interpreter.

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
    /**
     * This command line tool encodes all images contained in the specified HTML file.
     * The encoded contents will be returned on standard output.
     * Use redirection to store it into a file.
     * @author Massimiliano Alessandri <m.alessandri@spaziocolore.it>
     */
    /**
     * Converts a "src" property embedding the referenced image.
     * This way, the recipient won't have to click on "display images" to view the images.
     * @param array $matches the array sent by the preg_replace_callback function
     * @return string the encoded "src" property
     */
    function base64images($matches) {
            return 'src="data:'.mime_content_type($matches[1]).';base64,'.base64_encode(file_get_contents($matches[1])).'"';
    }
    if($argc < 2) {
        echo 'Usage: '.$argv[0].' [file to be encoded]';
        echo 'The encoded file will be returned to standard output.';
        exit;
    }
    $filename = $argv[1];
    if(file_exists($filename))
        echo preg_replace_callback('/src="([^"]+)"/', 'base64images', file_get_contents($filename));
    else
        echo 'File not found: '.$filename."\n";
```